# Master pasword authentication in firefox sdk addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

What is the command to ask the user to set master password in firefox sdk addon. If the user don't use a master password, then I need to make user set master password. How to do that. Which token function should I use to pop-up master password setting block.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
var me = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null);
var tokenDB = Cc['@mozilla.org/security/pk11tokendb;1'].getService(Ci.nsIPK11TokenDB);
var master_password = tokenDB.getInternalKeyToken();

var master_password_authenticated;
try {
    master_password_authenticated = Components.isSuccessCode(token.login(false)); //login argument is false meaning that if the user had previously entered their master password it will not prompt them now AND if they had not entered it before and it is still valid for the session it will NOT prompt. IF you set it to true then regardless if the user entered it in before or not it will force them to enter it again
} catch (ex) {
    master_password_authenticated = false;
}

me.alert('master passsword pass? = ' + master_password_authenticated);
```

This will tell you "If the user has a master password, are they authorized".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already read the above answer which was given by you in another question. I am not looking for this. I am able to know whether the user is using the master password or not. If the user is not using the master password, then which token command opens up the  master password setting pop-up and asks the user to set the master password. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SeelamVenkatanagasiva to reset the token I did this: `var token_db = Cc['@mozilla.org/security/pk11tokendb;1'].getService(Ci.nsIPK11TokenDB).getInternalKeyToken();
token_db.logoutAndDropAuthenticatedResources();` so do `console.log(token_db)` and there should be something in there to open authenticate. This is a screenshot of me doing this investigation - http://i.imgur.com/yNd6C7u.png - it seems theres a lot of stuff in there you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking for this only. Can you please give me the link of that website containing matter related to the photo you provided. So, that I can read other functions and understand which would be my option.

Comment: @SeelamVenkatanagasiva I simply opened browser console `Ctrl + Shift + J` (Cmd on Mac). then I did `console.log` - http://i.imgur.com/z4dB8ot.png

Comment: Sorry Noitidart. I couldn't  get anything from the browser console. I am very new to browser console. Could you please give matter related to stuff in image http://i.imgur.com/yNd6C7u.png Like how to change the password or reset the password, what parameters do they take, etc. Sorry for asking these many times. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SeelamVenkatanagasiva you will have to enable develoepr preferences first - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/devprefs/